# Possible bug: replaceReducer() fn repeats actions with wrong parameters

Tags: redux

Just have built hot reloading mechanisms in a large Redux app. When calling the `replaceReducer()` fn I can see that previous actions are repeated and processed in reducers, this to maintain app state. Which is expected

Luckily while testing one reducer crashed because of invalid arguments. After debugging I can see that one action wasn't repeated with the same arguments.

In my case it was an action called "select" to select a single row in a table. Arguments were an array of table rows and a boolean flag to select or unselect it. After replacing the reducer that action was executed again but with an empty array of rows, then crash.

Difficult to debug inside the redux code to find out who/where those arguments come from.

Using redux v3.7.2 here. Grateful for any hints/clues. Could be a bug or we are doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have the Redux DevTools Extension turned on?  That's likely trying to re-run things to handle the latest state.

Comment: Yes I have. They re-run things? Didn't know. Is this documented or even configurable?